# How to upload free magento extension on magento connect?

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

This question may sound very noob, but I am having troubles finding how to upload free extension on magento connect. I have checked magento manuals and magento connect account interface and cannot find where to upload extension files.

I was reading following official magento PDF manual: 
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

Section 3: Uploading Your Free Extension Package

> Once you’ve created your extension profile page with the information
>   required in the section above, you will need to upload your extension
>   package from the Versions Tab: NOTE: Remember – Your extension must be
>   packaged under the username of the developer uploading the extension.
>   Packaging in any other name will result in an error.[image]

As you can see there is no "Browse" nor upload button.

Thanks for your help.

---

### EDIT:

Here is 2 more screenshots of our account on magento connect (extension was approved 3 days ago)
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should post which browser(s) you are using and whether Flash works properly in it (them).

Comment: Hello @benmarks, I use Google Chrome 29.0.15 and IE 10. Flash works perfectly in my browsers. But I don't think it is related, as I don't have this section "Upload package file..." as on screenshot provided by Tim. I assume I should have it when I click on "Edit" Version link, or each time when I try to "add new version". Is this correct?

Comment: Your second screenshot is from editing the extension. What do you get when clicking "Add Version" and then the next step? Also can you edit the extension description itself, ie do you have any validation errors on the text, categories, etc?

Comment: And to answer your other question, when you click edit you can't reupload the same version.

Comment: @Fooman, even though I didnt have any file uploaded in my current version I still didnt have the upload button. I think it's because my extension was not free before. And after I converted it to a "free" - magento still didn't have the upload option. But now everything is fine. I just needed to create the "new version" again and now I have "continue to upload" step. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had "upload and save" button just because my extension was not free at first. And after I converted it into "free", magento connect didnt have this option when I tried to edit existing version. So the solution is simple - is to create new version. See screenshot below. Thanks to @Tim & @Fooman.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to upload the actual file at the next step after the screen you posted ;-)

[image]

Comment: Hello @Tim, the next step is "Section 4: Submitting Your Extension". Where you can press "Submit for Approval" button. That's it. The extension is currently approved, but I cannot find where to upload files. Am I missing something?

Comment: Then you will be able to upload the file once your extension is approved ;) Can take a while.

Comment: I just uploaded two more screenshots in my main post. I simply don't have that "upload and save" button. Our extension was approved 3 days ago...

Comment: thanks! I only have this option when I create new version, not when I edit existing one.

Comment: This is intended behavior. You can't upload file when you edit version, only when you create new one. I'm one of the developers who developed magento connect and we had such requirement from our business guys.

Comment: @Zyava, I see. It would be good to have this documented somewhere since you cannot find this info in official manual.

Comment: Unable to save version. Disallowed extension release file type. i am getting this error continues can you tell me which file supported??

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox "Is Free" in the submission form.