# How to upload Extension files in magento Connect

Tags: magento-connect

I am trying to upload my custom Extension in magento Connect. I am following this url http://www.gosolid.net/pages/info/index/page/how-to-add-magento-extension-using-magento-connect/ . I am able to upload ScreenShot Tile ,description . But I am not getting Interface to upload my extenion Files .without uploading files its asking for to Submit for approval. Can you help me out to provide Screen shot or Exact location to upload extension files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload free magento extension on magento connect?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8055/how-to-upload-free-magento-extension-on-magento-connect)

Comment: Leaving this open for now, but please answer: **Is your module marked as "free"?**