# Can publish a plugin in magento connect, which developed for my own website

Tags: magento-connect, plugin

I have been working on a project built on cake PHP. The project is an multivendor eCommerce platform.

The client for which I am building this application ,wants to create a magento plugin. This plugin will install on any magento powered ecommerce platform and communicate with the client multivendor ecommerce website.

I know, how we can developed such plugin. But what I don't know, is weather can I publish such plugin to MagentoConnect, which catered to specific application only. It would be great help if someone point me to acceptance criteria on publishing the plugin on magento.

I know how to publish a plugin in Magento Connect. But Does magento connect will accept a plugin in their portfolio, which is made for a specific website. And will be used by business client of that website only?

Comment: you can publish free extension on Magento Connect after packaging the extension. Please check this out http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload free magento extension on magento connect?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8055/how-to-upload-free-magento-extension-on-magento-connect)

Comment: @ochem  My question is not "how to publish plugin on magento", it "Can I publish such plugin in open community platform which caters to specific business need" and whats the acceptance criteria of publish any plugin on magento connect apart from design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines are not too strict *at the moment*. There are *major* changes coming in the next month or two with the launch of the new version of Connect. For now though it's enough to package your Magento extension via a Magento instance and upload to Connect.